# How to create "all-day" events with Google Calendar API

Tags: python-3.x, google-calendar-api

On [this page](https://developers.google.com/calendar/create-events) Google give the following example of how to create an event in a Google calendar:

```
event = {
  'summary': 'Google I/O 2015',
  'location': '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
  'description': 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
  'start': {
    'dateTime': '2015-05-28T09:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
  },
  'end': {
    'dateTime': '2015-05-28T17:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
  },
  'recurrence': [
    'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
  ],
  'attendees': [
    {'email': 'lpage@example.com'},
    {'email': 'sbrin@example.com'},
  ],
  'reminders': {
    'useDefault': False,
    'overrides': [
      {'method': 'email', 'minutes': 24 * 60},
      {'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 10},
    ],
  },
}

event = service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', body=event).execute()
print 'Event created: %s' % (event.get('htmlLink'))
```

This code works fine, but I am struggling to make an "all-day" event. I have seen it suggested that with an all day event the date string passed should be abbreviated to being just the date, e.g. "2020-05-08" but doing this results in an error `Invalid format: "2020-05-08" is too short"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to create an all-day event using googleapis with python.
- You want to know the reason of the error message of `Invalid format: "2020-05-08" is too short"`.

For this, how about this answer?

#### Modification point:

- When `2020-05-08` is used to the property of `dateTime`, such error occurs. In this case, please put it to the property of `date`.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

From:

```
'start': {
  'dateTime': '2015-05-28T09:00:00-07:00',
  'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
},
'end': {
  'dateTime': '2015-05-28T17:00:00-07:00',
  'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
},
```

To:

```
'start': {
  'date': '2020-05-08',
  'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
},
'end': {
  'date': '2020-05-08',
  'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
},
```

#### Reference:

- [Request body of Events: insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#request-body)

Comment: Is the timezone even relevant for all day events?

Comment: @NicoHood About your question of `Is the timezone even relevant for all day events?`, I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. So, can you post it as a new question by including more information? By this, it will help users think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: The `timezone` information should only be required for `datetime` objects, but for `date` also?

Comment: @NicoHood About your question of `The timezone information should only be required for datetime objects, but for date also?`, I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. So, can you post it as a new question by including more information? By this, it will help users think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?